# django - deleting image files

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django and jquery for image uploading. First we upload an image using the uploader, the image get stored in the `tmpbg` imagefield. Then if we click save button, the `tmpbg` will be moved to the background imagefield. Here what I need is I want to delete the orphaned image file in the background imagefield path.

Here is the code

Models.py:

```
class BackgroundModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds', null=True, blank=True)
    tmpbg = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds', null=True, blank=True)

class BackgroundModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BackgroundModel
        exclude = ('user', 'background')
```

Views.py (The code for deleting the image file in the path):

```
try:
    bg = BackgroundModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
except BackgroundModel.DoesNotExist:
    pass
else:
    if bg.background != '':
        image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(bg.background))
        try:
            os.unlink(image_path)
            bg.BackgroundModel.delete()
        except:
            pass

    bg.background = bg.tmpbg
return HttpResponse("")
```

But the orphaned imagefile is not deleted. What mistakes have I done?

UPDATE:

There is a problem in this line

```
bg.background=bg.tmpbg
```

When I checked in the shell mode. It shows none.

```
>>> g.background
<ImageFieldFile: None>
```

But there is an image file in tmpbg

```
>>> g.background
<ImageFieldFile: backgrounds/ijkl.jpg>
```

So, How can I copy from one imagefield to another field?

Between the image_path code is Correct!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `os.normpath`, this should do the trick :

```
 image_path = os.path.normpath(
     os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(bg.background))
 )
```

UPDATE :

```
try:
    bg = BackgroundModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
except BackgroundModel.DoesNotExist:
    pass
else:
    if bg.background != '':
        image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(bg.background))
        try:
            os.unlink(image_path)
        except:
            pass

    bg.background = bg.tmpbg
    bg.save()
 return HttpResponse("")
```

Comment: And without the str ? Something like image_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, bg.background))

Comment: Please Check my question now. Thanks!

Comment: bg.background.path is what you're after, you don't need normpath/join etc

Answer (score 1):

I would override the delete method of the model and add file delete there.
I would do something like:

```
class BackgroundModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def delete(self, using=None):
        os.unlink(self.tmpbg.path)
        super(BackgroundModel,self).delete()
```

I didn't check the code, but something like this should work. Tell me if it's not. :)

Comment: No, still it doesn't delete the image file. Please check the code I updated. I'm having tmpbg and background in the same model. So, It should not be deleted before transferring tmpbg to background. Am I right?

Comment: In order to copy the tmpbg to background I would still write your code in the delete method. In any case, try to print image_path after you calculate it, and check if it's correct. I think you should do something like:                                             image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(bg.tmpbg.filename))

Comment: Please Check my question now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try:
    bg = BackgroundModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
except BackgroundModel.DoesNotExist:
    pass
else:
    if bg.background:
        file_to_delete = bg.background.path
        bg.background = bg.tmpbg
        bg.save()
        try:
            os.unlink(file_to_delete)
        except:
            pass
return HttpResponse()
```

Also, assign `ImageFileField` to `ImageFileField` just copy the file path, thus if you do

```
g.background = g.tmpbg
g.save()
```

`g.background` and `g.tmpbg` will point to the same file. Once the file gets deleted through `g.background`, `g.tmpbg` will be unaccessible also. If you don't want this behavior, tell Django to save to a new file:

```
from django.core.files.base import File
g.background = File(g.tmpbg)
g.save()
```